# How to downgrade angular7 to angular6

Tags: typescript, npm, angular6, angular-cli, angular7

I have tried to downgrade **angular 7** to **angular 6** by running the following `npm` commands:

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g angular-cli@6.1.1
```

However `angular/cli` **7 version** is still displaying in my `package.json` file. I need help to downgrade `angular7` to `angular6`.

Comment: In package.json, change the version number in all packages that needs to be downgraded, then run `rm -rf node_modules` to remove everything, then run `npm i`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to set the version numbers in your `package.json` for (at least) this packages

```
"@angular/animations": "^7.0.0",
"@angular/cdk": "7.3.3",
"@angular/common": "^7.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "7.2.6",
"@angular/core": "7.2.6",
"@angular/forms": "^7.0.0",
"@angular/http": "^7.0.0",
"@angular/material": "7.3.3",
"@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^7.3.3",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^7.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.0.0",
"@angular/router": "^7.0.0",
"rxjs": "6.4.0",
```

as well as in dev-dependencies

```
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.6",
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.13.3",
"typescript": "3.2.4",
"@angular/cli": "~7.3.3",
```

Also make sure to downgrade every library that needs to be downgraded depending on angular's version. Check error messages after step 1...

Once you changed that, run

```
rm -rf node_modules
```

from the project's root folder to remove all packages

Then run

```
npm i
```

And you should be good to go

Comment: Hi bambam, i have install flexLayout for angular6 but i got following error  "Cannot find name 'MediaQueryListEventMap'" i have tried to solve but helped

Comment: check the packages github page to find which version supports angular 6, then change that in your package.json and do the same as described in the answer again, starting from deleting node_modules @SaranViji

Comment: Hi i solved by installed following version " npm install @angular/flex-layout@6.0.0-beta.18"

Comment: Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot the `@` before `@angular/cli`
Try these lines to make the change globally.

```
ng --version

npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean --force

npm install -g @angular/cli@6.1.1
ng --version
```

Use the same, going to your project folder, and without the `-g` to make the change locally.

Another way is to manually edit `package.json` file, remove `node_modules` folder and re run `npm install` in your project folder.

Comment: Op's but still angular/cli version not changed still display all version are 7

Comment: Can you execute this command to see your global version of angular/cli: `npm list -global --depth 0`

Comment: That's by far not enough

Comment: Or Else can change manually for 7 to 6 version?. Once i installed @angular/cli@6.1.1