# Can't resolve all parameters for Application Module: (?). at syntaxError (compiler.js:1021) site:stackoverflow.com

Tags: angular, npm, angular6, angular7

After downgrading my Angular project from version 7 to 6 and integrating Angular Universal with the help of @ngToolkit, I'm getting the following error message in the browser console:

```
Can't resolve all parameters for Application Module: (?). at syntaxError (compiler.js:1021)
```

I downgraded the project by simply overwriting the dependencies like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54900143/how-to-downgrade-angular7-to-angular6).
As already described the error only occurs in the browser console, while to compilation of the project is completing successfully.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/26128

Comment: Thank you, your reference helped a lot. There were actually some Polyfills missing, so I copied the polyfill.ts from a different project with Angular 6 and that fixed it. Would you mind writing an answer for future reference to help people with the same error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re apparently affected by [issue 26128](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/26128) that was introduced in Angular 6.1.8. As [IgorMinar](https://github.com/IgorMinar) [explained](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/26128#issuecomment-425511902) (emphasis mine):

> I noticed that in the past under certain circumstances you were able to use the JIT compiler without the Reflect.metadata polyfill. But with a recent change […], **we now require you to load it before anything from @angular/core is imported**. This will be done automatically *by cli v7* so the change will be transparent to *most* users, **unless you have a custom polyfill setup in which case you need to ensure that the polyfill is loaded before Angular**.

In case of Angular `^6.1.8 || ^7.0.0` with Webpack (i.e. not Angular CLI), you have to import `reflect-metadata` (before any @angular/core imports—as stated above).

Comment: What does the import statement look like? import reflect from 'reflect-metadata'?

Comment: @Jackie, I used just `import 'reflect-metadata'` in `index.ts` and `import 'core-js/es7/reflect'` in `polyfills.ts`. Your setup may require something different.